# 2 floating div's side by side, with no width

Tags: html, css

**html**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one">One</div>
    <div id="two">Two</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}

#one {
    width: 340px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}

#two {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 0px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
}
```

This is what i want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/p4ZAd/

I want to make a margin of 20px between the two divs and this is how far Iv'e gotten, but is it possible to do it any other way?

What i would idealy like is to remove the width on the "#one" completely and just have it be maximum size with a margin towards the "#two".

Comment: In the title you say “no margin” but in the text (and the code) you have a margin. Do you want one now or not? And where?

Comment: Totally missed that, thanks:) I do want to use a margin to seperate the two div's.

Comment: if you are using float make sure you put a clear:both to the next element or you would see bizarre things happening :)

Answer (score 0):

LIke this

**[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4ZAd/1/)**

**css**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    display:table;
}

#one {

    background-color: green;

    display:table-cell;
}

#two {

    background-color: blue;
   display:table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table` and `table-cell` display types to mimic how a `table` works. Then use `border-spacing` to accomplish the margin in-between cells.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one">One</div>

    <div id="two">Two</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    border-spacing: 20px;
}

#one {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: green;
}

#two {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/p4ZAd/2/)

[Here's a list of browsers that support `display: table;`](http://caniuse.com/#search=table)

Answer (score 0):

You can set padding on `#container` and then set negative right margin for `#two`. Example:

```
#container {
    width: 360px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px 140px 20px 20px;
}

#one {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#two {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 -120px 0 0;
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/SytvY/1/